# Is it possible to limit the dimensions/area of an editable shape in Google maps API v3 so that one cannot be drawn to large or small?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to be able to draw shapes (circles, polygons and rectangles) on a Google map but I would like to place limits on the size (area) of the shape that can be drawn. So taking a circle as an example, the desired behaviour would be that as the user starts dragging the mouse from a certain point on the map to form the circle , the circle would hit an invisible boundary and just stop expanding.

I'll define the *size/area* of the shape as the geographical area it covers. Ideally I would like to be able to stipulate limits on the geographical area that shape covers. So in the circle example, I could specify that the circle would stop expanding when the geographical area it covers reaches, say 10 square kilometres, regardless of the viewport zoom level.

I haven't though how this would work for drawing a polygon but I'm sure it's a bit more complicated because of the fact that a polygon is drawn in stages (multiple clicks)... but one step at a time.

Comment: So you want to be checking the size of the geometry while they're still editing, not afterwards? If it were afterwards, you could just get the area, and send a message to the user about it being too big/small

Comment: Sure he can, but it is better to restrict shape stretching for user, then pop-up windows by JS for example - that is why this question interesting for me either.

Answer (score 5):

This is the best solution I could come up with for the circle scenario. Note, that this doesn't explicitly stop the circle's resize as it's being edited, but as soon as the user releases the resize, the circle snaps back to the maximum allowed size.

May not be ideal per chrismarx & zeusakm notes above, but there doesn't appear to be any native way with google's api to set a strict boundary on size as the user resizes.

```
var shapeOptions = {
  fillColor: '#ff0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.50,
  map: map, // your map
  center: curLocation, // geo starting point
  draggable: true,
  editable: true,
  radius: 30 // initial circle radius in meters
};

// Add the circle to the map.
newCircle = new google.maps.Circle(shapeOptions);

var maxRadius = 100; // whatever max size you want to dictate

google.maps.event.addListener(newCircle,'radius_changed',function(){
    if (this.getRadius() > maxRadius) {
        this.setRadius(maxRadius);
    }
});
```

If you want to create something totally custom, this solution may also be of use:
[How to know radius while drawing a circle on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368231/how-to-know-radius-while-drawing-a-circle-on-google-maps)